# django rest framework get all related fields and filter in a manytomany field nested

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django I want to get all informations of my contacts for a store given in parameter and all extra from another model.

> *Here is my code :*

**Models.py**

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
​
​
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Store, related_name='contacts')
​
​
class DataType(models.Model):
    datatype = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class DataField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datatype = models.ForeignKey(
        'DataType',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )


class DataFieldValue(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='datafieldvalues',
        null=True
    )
    datafield = models.ForeignKey(
        'DataField',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    value = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

**Views.py**

```py
# Contact API views.
class ContactListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    filter_class = ContactFilter
```

**Filters.py**

```py
class ContactFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    store = django_filters.CharFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['store']
```

**Serializers.py**

```py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

> *(Additionnal) Here is the schema :*
>   [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN5fl.png)

this is what i want:

> GET /contacts/?store=54

```
{
    "count": 25,
    "next": "<url>/contacts/?page=3",
    "previous": "<url>/contacts/?page=2",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "a519d2cd-13c6-48f3-b391-9a7e0cee58cc",
            "src_id": 356,
            "first_name": "Benjamin",
            "last_name": "Pavard",
            "email": "benjamin.pavard@email.fr",
            "datafields" : {
                "age" : "eighteen"
            },
            "store": 54
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

but this is what i got :

```
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "count": 10,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1234567",
            "first_name": null,
            "last_name": null,
            "email": "cartouche@email.fr",
        },
        .....
}
```

> *Questions :*

how can i get the "datafields" ?
"age" is a "datafield" object and "eighteen" is a datafieldvalue object.

How can i get only the store that i've previously gave in parameter?

Thanks a lot for your help whatever it was.

Comment: Here is the doc https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend you are not very far from having it ;)

Comment: I think you need to add `prefetch_related` in your query.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan thanks but it's doesn't work, except when i write Contact.objects.all().prefect_related('stores') , but this is not exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add more fields in the `ContactSerializer`

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    datafields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_datafields(self, obj):
        result = {}
        for data_field_value in obj.datafieldvalues.all().select_related('datafield'):
            result[data_field_value.datafield.label] = data_field_value.value
        return result

    def get_store(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        store = request.query_params.get('store', '')
        return store
```

Comment: Thank you but for the store, i want to type http://[url]/contact/?store=54 and get => "store": 54 <= not "store": [ 54, 55, 70 ] is that possible to do that in the filter ?

Comment: I'm Trying to have a filter, not just put a field "store" in the response, if the contact isn't in the store 54 he doesn't have to be in the result